# Nohup process not running into ssh

Tags: ssh, nohup

I have a question on the use of `nohup` in an `ssh` session. During more than three years my java software executed the following command daily using a remote ssh session:

```
cd some_path; chmod 777 script.sh; ./script.sh
```

the content of script is:

```
nohup java java_command parameters &
```

It's simple and working perfectly all the time in red hat machines.

In a new software installation using the same environment the command is not working. It is also not working if I execute it manually from any remote ssh session. However, if I change the content of `script.sh`, removing the `nohup` and `&`, then the command works properly.

What can be the problem? The ssh settings are the same. The only difference that I found is that `umask` is `0012` in the new installation and in the original installation it was `0022`.

Additional info: The original installation is a RHEL 5.4 and the new installation is a RHEL 6.3. Is the 6.3 version more restrictive by default?

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Is `nohup` available on the new system? Everyone allowed to execute it?

Comment: Probably not relevant to your problem, but you do *not* want mode 777. That allows write permission to everyone, which is exceptionally dangerous for something you're about to execute. You probably want 700.

Answer (score 2):

Has your login shell changed?

Give this a try. Edit your script and change `nohup` to `/usr/bin/nohup`.

The reason it might be the solution is that login shells, such as the C shell, have their own version of "nohup". The C shell (or tcsh) nohup accepts a command but not a command argument. On the otherhand, /usr/bin/nohup can take a COMMAND and an optional command argument which is the way that you are using nohup.

Comment: Thanks ZaSter! I'll try it shortly and I will comment you the results.